# SQL Query - Selecting last recorded values for each date in specified period

Tags: database, date, select, max, ms-access-2010

Can someone please help me with my problem which is getting last recorded balance for each day for specific box (1 or 2) in specified period of days.

For example, my table looks like this:

Table name: TestTable

`Date         Time      Location  Box  Balance
20.10.2014.  06:00:00     1       1    345
20.10.2014.  12:00:00     1       1    7356
20.10.2014.  18:45:00     1       1    5678
20.10.2014.  23:54:00     1       1    9845
20.10.2014.  06:00:02     1       2    35
20.10.2014.  12:00:04     1       2    756
20.10.2014.  18:45:06     1       2    578
20.10.2014.  23:54:10     1       2    845
21.10.2014.  06:00:00     1       1    34
21.10.2014.  12:05:03     1       1    5789
21.10.2014.  15:00:34     1       1    1237
21.10.2014.  06:00:00     1       2    374
21.10.2014.  12:05:03     1       2    54789
21.10.2014.  15:00:34     1       2    13237
22.10.2014.  06:00:00     1       1    8562
22.10.2014.  10:00:00     1       1    1234
22.10.2014.  17:03:45     1       1    3415
22.10.2014.  22:00:00     1       1    6742
22.10.2014.  06:00:05     1       2    562
22.10.2014.  10:00:16     1       2    123
22.10.2014.  17:03:50     1       2    415
22.10.2014.  22:00:10     1       2    642
23.10.2014.  06:00:00     1       1    9876
23.10.2014.  09:13:00     1       1    223
23.10.2014.  13:50:17     1       1    7768
23.10.2014.  19:47:40     1       1    3456
23.10.2014.  21:30:00     1       1    789
23.10.2014.  23:57:12     1       1    25
23.10.2014.  06:00:07     1       2    976
23.10.2014.  09:13:45     1       2    223
23.10.2014.  13:50:40     1       2    78
23.10.2014.  19:47:55     1       2    346
23.10.2014.  21:30:03     1       2    89
23.10.2014.  23:57:18     1       2    25
24.10.2014.  06:00:55     1       1    346
24.10.2014.  12:30:22     1       1    8329
24.10.2014.  23:50:19     1       1    2225
24.10.2014.  06:01:00     1       2    3546
24.10.2014.  12:30:26     1       2    89
24.10.2014.  23:51:10     1       2    25
...`

Let's say the period is 21.10.2014. - 23.10.2014. and I want to get last recorded balance for box 1. for each day.
The result should look like this:

`Date         Time      Location  Box  Balance
21.10.2014.  15:00:34     1       1    1237
22.10.2014.  22:00:00     1       1    6742
23.10.2014.  23:57:12     1       1    25`

So far I've managed to write a query that gives me balance for ONLY ONE date (date with highest time in whole table), but I need balance for EVERY date in specific period.

My incorrect code:

`SELECT TestTable.[Date], TestTable.[Time], TestTable.[Location], TestTable.[Box], TestTable.[Balance]
FROM TestTable
WHERE Time=(SELECT MAX(Time)
FROM TestTable
WHERE Location=1 AND Box=1 );`

Please have in mind I'm very new in this.

Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

What youre looking for is the GROUP BY statement and moving your MAX a little bit:

```
SELECT TestTable.[Date], MAX(TestTable.[Time]), TestTable.[Location],TestTable.[Box], 
TestTable.[Balance] FROM TestTable WHERE Location=1 AND Box=1 GROUP BY TestTable.[Date];
```

You also wanted to select a certain time period, I'm not familiar with using the date format in your table, but youll get the idea:

```
SELECT ... WHERE TestTable.[Date] BETWEEN '21.10.2014.' AND '23.10.2014.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things -

Firstly, you don't need to add the `FROM` again before you add another `WHERE` clause. (Unless you're using a subquery but thats a whole other thing). You would just do -

```
FROM MyTable
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3
```

Secondly, if you want the `MAX` Time for *each* date, just add a `GROUP BY`.

```
GROUP BY Date
```

This means that it will show the `MAX` Time for each date.

---

```
SELECT 
Date, 
MAX(Time) AS LastTime, 
Balance
FROM 
TestTable   
WHERE Location=1 AND Box=1 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY Date
```

This shows you the `Date`, the last time in that day (the `MAX(Time)`), and the balance of that entry.